# Update table with sum from other table for the same id

Tags: postgresql

Given two tables:

Table **src**

```
user_id | counter | text
------------------------
5       | 1       | aa
7       | 7       | bb
```

Table **dst**

```
user_id | counter | text
------------------|-----
3       | 5       | ee
7       | 6       | ff
```

I need to do the following:

If row with user_id exists in **src** table but not exists in **dst** table - copy it from src to dst

If row with same user_id exists in both tables, then update the counter in dst with sum of counter from src and counter from dst, and overwrite the text

Final **dst** should be like that

Table **dst**

```
user_id | counter | text
------------------------
3       | 5       | ee
5       | 1       | aa
7       | 13      | bb
```

I started to insert the rows with missing user_id:

```
insert into dst 
select * 
from src as s 
where s.user_id not in (select d.user_id from dst as d);
```

How do I do the update for the exist user_id values?

**UPDATE:**

What will be the answer in case I have key of two columns user_id and group_id?

Answer (score 2):

this should do what you want

```
update dst
   set counter = dst.counter + src.counter
from src
where src.user_id = dst._user_id;
```

If `dst.user_id` is the primary key (or defined as unique), you can combine both into one statement:

```
insert into dst (user_id, counter, text)
select user_id, counter, text
from src 
on conflict (user_id) 
do update
  set counter = dst.counter + excluded.counter;
```

Comment: "set counter = src.counter" may be should be "set counter = src.counter+dst.counter" right? I need the sum of counters

Comment: Yes, if you want to add the values you need `+`

Comment: What will be the answer if I have key of two columns user_id and group_id